# Is it a good idea to make one instrumentation amplifier with three operational amplifiers for thermistor sensing circuits?

Tags: operational-amplifier, instrumentation-amplifier

Is it a good idea to have those three amplifiers with LM741 Operational amplifier? Has anyone done this so far? I thought of this as this was a cheapest idea. The instrumentation amplifier costs about $6 but the quad LM741 costs like $2. I know that buying instrumentation amplifier would be most effcient. But does anyone see any huge disadvantage in this making of instrumentation amplifier with three LM741 op-amps?

[image: instrumentation amplifier]

Comment: Please don't use '741s.

Comment: For thermocouple use? Not sure which type thermocouple you plan to use, but in general: no, absolutely not, don't waste your time, forget about it. For a lower gain application, sure, fine and dandy learning excercise.

Comment: sorry, not thermocouple but I am using a thermistor for accurately measuring the voltage across and inputing to the ADC of FPGA. I am still researching about the kind of buffer they have in Spartan 3E. If the buffer has really high input impedance and voltage requirement, I may not even have to use any amplifiers.

Comment: A thermistor is not a thermocouple, that changes things and you should edit the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible, but the CMRR (common mode rejection ratio) will be worse than a monolithic InAmp.  In a monolithic InAmp, the resistors R1-R3 are matched.  Also, they are on the same die at the same temperature.

By the way, the above holds independent of the OpAmp model.

[A Designer's Guide to Instrumentation Amplifiers](http://www.analog.com/en/specialty-amplifiers/instrumentation-amplifiers/ad620/products/design-handbooks/CU_dh_designers_guide_to_instrumentation_amps/resources/fca.html) has more on inner workings and rationale behind the design of InAmps.

Building an InAmp with 3 separate OpAmps could be a neat learning exercise**.  You can plug in different OpAmps and compare results.  You can compare CMRR with a factory-made monolithic InAmp.

** As Matt wrote in his comment.  He had beat me to it.

Comment: I saw an app note from ADI or TI that compared a monolithic and homebrew INA. The results were shocking, just wish I could come up with a search term that would find it.

Comment: @MattYoung  [This is more of a reply to your comment under the O.P.]  It also depends on the temperature range, which the O.P. is interested in, and on the desired accuracy.  TC measurement in a kiln around 700°C with accuracy of ±10°C are easier to pull off, compared to a medical thermometer at 37°C with accuracy of ±0.1°C.  Most of the standard thermocouple types output between 20 and 70 μV/°C.

Comment: @MattYoung: Sorry, What you mean by shocking! were the results of monolithic and homebrew INA were same or totally different?

Comment: @dr3patel The homebrew INA was much, much worse.

Comment: @MattYoung can you provide the link of above mentioned app note

Comment: @yogece Found it, the comparison was actually in the AD620 datasheet. http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD620.pdf starting at the bottom of PDF page 13.

Comment: @MattYoung  You should make an answer out of it.  If you don't, I'm tempted to roll it into my post with attribution to you.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Go ahead, I don't have much else to add that hasn't been said already.